# Animate UIView as flipboard in iOS

Tags: xcode, uiviewanimation

I tried to use [MPFoldTransition](https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition) for my UIView animation. But I want it like flipboard. That is, it should be animated as per the user touch.

Please help me that how can I achieve it. Also, is there any other library for UIView animation like flipboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a library for this flip, [MPFlipViewController](https://github.com/mpospese/MPFlipViewController) uses MPFoldTransition and works with a pan gesture.

Also, take a look at https://github.com/ITechRoof/ITRFlipper

If you want to build this yourself and have a true flip like Flipboard (where it flips in the middle, with appropriate shadows), taking a snapshot of the view and using a simple matrix transform can do the trick. I'm not going to go into all the details as I could talk for hours about animation timing and shadows.